# Adding marker to map by clicking on it

Tags: c#, google-maps, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am developing an app that uses maps and GPS and allows the user to make a pin/marker on map and paves the way from his current location to the place that he marked. I need to add a "standard" marker/pin to map by clicking on the place that I need to go. There is no problem to add it in code:

```
var position = new Position(37, -122); // Latitude, Longitude
            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.Place,
                Position = position,
                Label = "custom pin",
                Address = "custom detail info"
            };
            map.Pins.Add(pin);
```

But I need exactly to add it by click. Because the user will not go to code and he will not add a marker/pin there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could either install the [TK.CustomMap](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap) plugin (or other similar plugins that have this functionality, TK.CustomMap is just the first I found but I have never tried it myself) and use it's [Map Clicked Command](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/wiki/TKCustomMap#mapclickedcommand) which provides a `Position` where the map was clicked.

Or you could copy the code they used to make that functionality work. Below are some links to where they define that `Command` in the shared code and where they hook up the `Command` to the native map class in the iOS and Android projects (they also probably have WP code but I just can't be bothered for a platform with < 1% market share).

[Shared](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/blob/1f12aa0865a50e449f12c4568aeb777a63dd772d/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap/TKCustomMap.cs#L29)

[Android](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/blob/1f12aa0865a50e449f12c4568aeb777a63dd772d/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.Android/TKCustomMapRenderer.cs#L72)

[iOS](https://github.com/TorbenK/TK.CustomMap/blob/1f12aa0865a50e449f12c4568aeb777a63dd772d/TK.CustomMap/TK.CustomMap.iOSUnified/TKCustomMapRenderer.cs#L121)